# i have button on click change text ant i want to save change in local storage

Tags: javascript, html

i have a ten buttons on click change text button and not saving change what is the problem?
and please write your code
html code

```js
var activeButton = localStorage.getItem('activeButton');
var isActive = localStorage.getItem('isActive');

const allButtons = doStuff(document.querySelectorAll(".button");
    [...allButtons].forEach(function(thisButton) {
      if (isActive === 'true') {
        if (activeButton !== thisButton.id) {
          thisButton.disabled = true;
        }
      }
    });
    const movetool = event => {
        activeButton = localStorage.getItem('activeButton');
        const target = event.target.closest("button");
        if (activeButton === target.id) {
          var enableAll = false;
          Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
            if (thisButton.disabled) {
              enableAll = true;
              return;
            }
          });
          if (enableAll) {
            Array.from(allButtons).forEach(function(thisButton) {
              thisButton.disabled = false;
              target.innerHTML = "click";
              thisButton.innerHTML = "click";
            });
```

```html
<button class="button" id="movetool" onclick="movetool()">click 1</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool2" onclick="movetool2()">click 2</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool3" onclick="movetool3()">click 3</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool4" onclick="movetool4()">click 4</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool5" onclick="movetool5()">click 5</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool6" onclick="movetool6()">click 6</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool7" onclick="movetool7()">click 7</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool8" onclick="movetool8()">click 8</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool9" onclick="movetool9()">click 9</button>
<button class="button" id="movetool10" onclick="movetool10()">click 10</button>
```

Comment: You save items to localstorage with localStorage.setItem('itemName', 'itemValue').

Comment: I know this, but the code does not work when doing a reload. It returns everything as it was

Comment: I don't see you use setItem anywhere though?

Comment: you know that but you don't use in your code

Comment: What you want is to save the values and then restore them if the user refreshes the page, and that's a completely different question. Try to be specific next time.

Answer (score 0):

The function that saves items to local storage is localStorage.setItem('itemName', 'itemValue')

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
localStorage.setItem('myItem', 'item value')
})
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```